# How can you loop through a column and ensure that all associated rows are accounted for in order

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am attempting to search through column C for a specific string from an array and print all of the associated data in that row. However, I need all information that has a matching column C and column D to be printed under the same header. I cannot figure out how to ensure that all data is printed in order under the right headers without repeating data. My code for this particular section is listed below.

An example of my input data looks like this:

[image: Example Data Sheet]

Ideally, it would print like this:

[image: Good Data]

Instead, it looks like this:

[image: Bad Data]

In mind it would work like this: Check column C for info stored in the array, when something is found check column D. Then move through the entire sheet looking for other instances of data that have the same column C and column D and print this data with a header. Move back to the top of the sheet and search for the matching column C with a different column D, print that data and continue through for the entire array.

I don't know how to accomplish this without having matching column D information under a different header, or endlessly printing array position 0.

```
'Check the array for each ICAO and begin writing unit taskings
For Each chkString In iCAOArray
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Admin Data").Range("C5:C1000")
    rng.Find(chkString).Select
    conICAO = ActiveCell
    startAddress = ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    conCallsign = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    conAC = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    conUnit = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    rng.FindNext(ActiveCell).Select

        Print #1, ("SVCTASK/" & letterArray(arrayCheck) & "//")
        Print #1, ("TASKUNIT/" & conUnit & "/ICAO:" & conICAO & "//")
        arrayCheck = arrayCheck + 1
    
    While ActiveCell.Address <> startAddress
    conICAOCurrent = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    conCallsignCurrent = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    conACCurrent = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    conUnitCurrent = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    
    'Moves to next unit tasking
    If conUnitCurrent = conUnit Then
        Print #1, ("Units are same")
    Else
        Print #1, ("SVCTASK/" & letterArray(arrayCheck) & "//")
        Print #1, ("TASKUNIT/" & conUnitCurrent & "/ICAO:" & conICAO & "//")
        arrayCheck = arrayCheck + 1
        conUnit = conUnitCurrent
    End If
    rng.FindNext(ActiveCell).Select
    Wend
    
Next chkString
```

Comment: What is the issue with your code? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error and on what line? If not, what is the actual issue? Also, it would be helpful to see your sheet or a sample sheet

Comment: @Zac My code works as written, however it doesn't achieve my desired endstate. I can't figure out how to format in the comments so see my original post for my sheet and desired outcome.